# Where do i see bitbucket-pipelines.yml after configuring it?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have configured  bitbucket-pipelines.yml, but i can't find the window i was configuring it with.
If i go to the **Deployments** menu on bitbucket, i see the following picture and i have no option of changing my pipeline anymore. It just says: Deployment tracking with Bitbucket.

[image]
How am i able to change the pipeline again?

In another repository, which i have not configured yet, this screen loads and i am able to configure my bitbucket pipeline.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this answer from the support, if anyone is interested:

Where does the bitbucket-pipelines.yml file reside ?

You will be able to see the bitbucket-pipelines.yml file on the main branch once pipelines is enabled on your repository
How do I know pipelies is enabled and how can I enable it ?

You can find the pipelines settings by accessing the repository settings > Pipelines > Toggle to enable pipelines
Other ways to access bitbucket-pipelines.yml ?

1. You can access it from the repository source section:
2. You can go to a build and click on the GEAR icon next to the build it will redirect you to the pipelines.yml page
3. You can navigate to the commit that recorded the change to the Bitbucket-pipelines.yml file, this will have a link to the YML file